# High side MOSFET extremely hot in a half bridge circuit

Tags: capacitor, pwm, h-bridge, gate-driving

The high side MOSFET becomes extremely hot when I try to run the half bridge, and the output does not seem right.

The PWM signals to Hin and Lin come from an Arduino - 47.5% duty cycle, dead time of 132ns, switching at 3.14kHz.

What could have been the problem?

1. Is my deadtime too small? I tried increasing it to 40usec. and did not see a change.
2. Is it the placement of ground right? Should it be moved from P1 to P2? If so, what should the polarities of C3 and C4 be?
3. Should C1 and C2 be electrolytic or ceramic? (http://tahmidmc.blogspot.com/2013/01/using-high-low-side-driver-ir2110-with.html mentions that ceramic capacitors should go parallel to electrolytic capacitors).
4. I am using 220uF, 250V capacitors for C3 and C4, could they be an issue as well?

In the picture below, the yellow wave form corresponds to the gate input of the high side switch, the blue waveform corresponds to the gate input of the low side switch and the purple waveform corresponds to the output across the output resistor Rload-1kohm.

[image]
[image]

Comment: C1 should be ceramic. Electrolytic is too slow (too much inductance). You can use a scope to see how long your high-side MOSFET is taking to turn on. Your scope image is too small to really be useful but the waveforms look at at least from the low detail that I can discern.

Comment: Thank you for your comments! I shall do that, I have edited the scope screenshot.

Comment: I almost want to say change your diode to a faster one like a 1N4448, but your waveforms don't show any refresh issues. But you should do that anyways since the 1N4004 is meant to rectify 60Hz, not refresh at kHz. Your grounds are correct. Do not change. The IRF2113 is a unipolar device and P2 is not the point of lowest potential in the system. There is some weirdness in how your LO side gate drive signal seems to try and follow the high drive gate-drive signal.

Comment: Great, thanks so much! I shall changing the diode and give an update!

Comment: There is some weirdness in how your LO side gate drive signal seems to try and follow the high drive gate-drive signal. Find out what is causing that. What is the voltage on the LO side gate drive when the HI-side gate drive is high?

Comment: I am using 220uF, 250V capacitors for C3 and C4, could they be an issue as well?

Comment: No, I don't think that's a problem. They don't cause any inductive kick or anything like that.

Comment: Curious...how are you measuring across Rload and the gate-drive signals relative to ground at the same time on your scope? Do you have differential probes? Because you either need to be subtracting two signals to produce the voltage across Rload or you need differential probes since the signals have different references.

Comment: Yes, I am using a differential probe to measure the voltage across the Rload.
While for for high side MOSFET gate input I measure Vgs_high and for low side MOSFET I measure Vg-ground using normal probes.

Comment: Just checking..

Comment: What is the voltage at the gate input to the upper FET when on? It looks like it is only 18V which only gives it ~3V VGS. That isn't enough. The IRF830 needs 10V to fully turn on.

Comment: @KevinWhite Oh you're right. I had assumed those were the logic signal being given to the gate driver and didn't notice they were 15V and actually the gate-source voltage. That's the problem there. But I don't see any obvious reason why the boostrap charge is not getting floated up.

Comment: Why is there a step in the LO side drive when the HI side is on? You could be having shoot-through.

Comment: That step almost looks like there is leakage between gate and drain of low-side MOSFET. It can't be damaged could it?

Comment: You could use your differential probe to measure the actual VGS on the HI side to get good accuracy.

Comment: @DKNguyen - I wonder if grounds are bad - that could cause the step but wouldn't seem to cause the low drive.

Comment: Hey @KevinWhite, thank you for answering. The yellow waveform corresponds to VGS-high which is 18V and blue waveform corresponds to VGS-lowside is 18V as well.. So, IRF830 gates are getting >10V. Sure, I shall use a differential probe to check it VGS on high side.

Comment: What supply do you have - is it 15V as shown in the schematic?

Comment: Yes Kevin, I have 15V as shown in the schematic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *switching at 3.14kHz*

You can't expect the bootstrapping circuit to work at such a low frequency with such low value bootstrap capacitors. In other words, you upper MOSFET gate drive signal runs out of steam and turns the upper MOSFET into a regular source follower dropping several volts across it.

Comment: I wondered about that but there's no evidence in the scope trace of any droop.

Comment: OP should provide a differential probe of the bootstrap cap voltage relative to the HI side gate drive signal. That would confirm. But to me it almost looks like the bootstrap is not there at all and the HI side is being directly driven by a GND referenced 15V, rather than running out of steam.

Comment: @KevinWhite I may be wrong but if you look at the yellow voltage waveform (high side gate switch) there is only about 15 volts p-p and I'm unsure where the DC level is pitched so, I guess what I'm saying is that I cannot tell from the yellow signal whether it's good or not. It might be but there's certainly no evidence that the boot circuit will work with 3 kHz.

Comment: Thank you for your inputs, I shall attach the differential probe waveform for the bootstrap capacitor voltage soon!

Comment: @Ruhi don’t go accepting my answer quite so quickly until you have proven this 100%.

Comment: Sure, undone it

Comment: Dear all, thank you so much for your feedback. I changed the frequency from 3kHz to 25 kHz, my MOSFET did not heat up. So, I think it was the bootstrap capacitors. 
To confirm the same, I replaced the bootstrap with an independent DC source clamping the high side MOSFET and in this case too my MOSFET did not heat up. Thank you!

Comment: @Ruhi that's good news. Of course if you need 3 kHz performance you could increase the value of the boot capacitor to around 4.7 uF. Maybe worth a try.

Comment: @Ruhi If the bootstrap cap was too small, how come your Vgs for the HI side MOSFET was not reading a drop in voltage in the graph you posted?